# Código que da el valor a un txt, dependiendo de la elección del combobox

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente código que hace que al elegir un dato del combobox, automáticamente aparezca el valor en el textbox. Este código hace una comparación con una tabla de access y toma el valor y lo coloca en el txt según la selección en combobox. Ejem

Si elijo el insumo alcohol en el form, automáticamente en el campo precio aparece el precio del alcohol que está en la tabla de access.

El tema es que tengo 15 combobox de insumos y quiero poder modificar el código para no tener que generar 15 variables para poder escribir el código.

Ayuda por favor.

```
Sub insertarlab()

Dim mm As Object
Dim put As Object
Dim consultaSQ As String
Dim conexion As String
Dim name As String 'aquí se le quitó el tipo de variable

Set mm = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=G:\Mi unidad\Saphi medical\software de costeo\basecosteo.accdb"
name = costoventa.i1.Value
consultaSQ = "Select * from insumoslab where Nombre = " & Chr(34) & name & Chr(34)
mm.Open conexion
Set put = mm.Execute(consultaSQ)
If Not put.EOF Then
    
costoventa.p1.Value = put.Fields(2) 
mm.Close
   
   End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hola Ambar, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y en donde dice "etiquetas" agregues las que corresponden al lenguaje que estás usando, de esa forma, lograrás que los que dominen dicho lenguaje, se interesen en revisarla.

Comment: Hazte un sub que dependiendo del combobox, se conecte a una tabla o a otra. Un Select Case de toda la vida

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a plantear el select case por favor?